# wordpress switch statement within the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to use a switch statement within the worpdpress loop to change classes on a div, but the incrementing counter ($IntCounter) doesn't seem to be firing within the loop:

```
<?php
global $intCounter;
$intcounter = 0;
query_posts('category_name=clients&posts_per_page=3&tag=new-work');
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $intcounter++;
        switch ($intcounter){
            case 1:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-7 colborder ";
                break;
            case 2:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-8 colborder ";
                break;
            case 3:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-7 last";
                break;
            default:{
                $ThisPostCSSClass="noclass";
            }

        }

    ?>
<div class="<?php echo $ThisPostCSSClass;?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .post -->
    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: are you getting expected output without the correct class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are grabbing the global `$intCounter;` but setting and incrementing `$intcounter;`
Not sure this is the problem because you're initializing `$intcounter=0;` and incrementing it correctly. So this only means the `global $intCounter;` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Chris - well spotted, that's exactly what it was! I've been staring at that for an hour!

Comment: Always helps to have a fresh pair of eyes sometimes.  Never hurts stepping away from it and getting breath of fresh air (in my case smoking a cigarette) and then coming back to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this has something to do with your usage of `global`.  Normally it's used within a scope to tell it that you want to use the *globally defined* version of the variable and not the local one.

I went ahead and redid the structure of the code blocks (for aesthetics, please humor me) with curly braces and removed the global keyword.  Try giving this chunk a try and see if it works for you:

```
<?php

query_posts('category_name=clients&posts_per_page=3&tag=new-work');

if(have_posts()) {
    $intcounter = 0; // Moved this to within the IF block

    while(have_posts()){
        // If you did want to use the "global" keyword, you'd probably use it here:
        // global $intcounter;

        the_post(); 
        $intcounter++;

        switch ($intcounter){
            case 1:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-7 colborder ";
                break;
            case 2:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-8 colborder ";
                break;
            case 3:
                $ThisPostCSSClass ="new-work-post span-7 last";
                break;
            default:  // Curly braces not required here.
                $ThisPostCSSClass="noclass";
        } // Switch

?>
<div class="<?php echo $ThisPostCSSClass;?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .post -->
<?php

    } // While

} // If
?>
```

Comment: Thanks GigaWatt, You're right, I didn't need the 'global' declaration. Nicely formatted code! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got a capital C in your global $intCounter but you are incrementing and switching on $intcounter. This initializes 2 different variables.
The switch statement and loop works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Why branches around default, and for the switch, but not for the if nor the while? Makes the code much harder to read. Also not sure why you're using a global for $intcounter (which btw has a C instead of a c), unless there's a reason for that that I dont know. Other than that seems that it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use ":" for your stamentlists, but use Curly brackets { }.

Eg:

```
if(have_posts()) {
   while(have_posts()) {
       the_post(); 
       $intcounter++;
       switch ($intcounter){
           case 1:
             ...
             ...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The way he has it is fine.  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> is perfectly acceptable.